# How to separate piece

Tags: modeling

I select vertexs and separate to piece. I press p to separate. The piece doesn't become what i selected. How do i separate everything i selected to a piece?[image]

enter image description here

[image][image]

Comment: what does it give if you select one vertex of the new object and press on the Make Root button of the Skin modifier?